# how to run asp.net sample project on microsoft visual web developer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i have downloaded this sample project from this http://www.freestudentprojects.com/studentprojectreport/projectreport/asp-net-social-networking/ and i cannot run this in my visual studio.There are so many errors shown up.Where do i need to configure so that i can run this successfully in my visual studio.

p.s-i have follow the instruction ,click the web configuration but when i click the security tab the error says that cannot find data source.

Comment: can you post some of your errors

Comment: If you want to be a student, you should work with projects from which you can _learn_, not just copy-paste garbage.

Comment: Agreed, dump that crud, do more reading.

Comment: At the face value it appears that datasource is missing but you need to show the code.